# Detect Facebook user agent in .htaccess file and disable gzip

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, gzip

Issue with Facebook not recognizing images due to use of gzip on our servers.

First off our websites need to use gzip so the answer of turning gzip off isnt an applicable response. Our servers use gzip by default and it's a good thing so we need to keep that in place.

I understand that gzipping images might have negligible impact but we are using it nonetheless.

What Im looking to do (hopefully) is ideally turn of gzip if the website is visited by a Facebook bot and leave gzip enabled otherwise so when the user agent detected is either of the

following...

> facebookexternalhit/1.0
>
> facebookexternalhit/1.1
>
> Facebot

We disable gzip (ie. SetEnv no-gzip 1 I assume)

We want to do this within each sites .htaccess file

Is there a way to do this in an .htaccess file, if so can anyone supply an .htaccess sample.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Why not just turn off gzip for all images? You are just wasting CPU on your server and on visitors computers and phones for no reason at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be gzipping images anyway.

http://gtmetrix.com/enable-gzip-compression.html

> Gzip compression won't work for images, PDF's and other binary formats which are already compressed.

Here is a good sample of mime types that work well with gzip:

```
application/atom+xml
application/javascript
application/json
application/rss+xml
application/vnd.ms-fontobject
application/x-font-ttf
application/x-web-app-manifest+json
application/xhtml+xml
application/xml
font/opentype
image/svg+xml
image/x-icon
text/css
text/plain
text/x-component;
```

https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/3db5d61f81d7229d12b89e0355629249a49ee4ac/nginx.conf#L93

Also see: https://superuser.com/a/139273

Comment: Yes maybe I should look at simply disabling gzipping images, seems like the only way to accomplish this.

Thanks